# Kubernetes on aws displays hex code on the external ip address

Tags: kubernetes

After following the link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/load-balance-access-application-cluster/ to create a service and expose the replica set.

The output shows the internal IP address as Hex code.

```
$ kubectl get services example-service
NAME              CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP        PORT(S)          AGE
example-service   100.66.5.159   a75af4afc61af...   8080:32114/TCP   1h
```

Here is my Kubernetes environment.

The Kubernetes cluster is running on AWS was deployed with kops version 1.6.0 and kubelet version 1.6.4. Everything is working fine with the internal cluster including DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the address of the ELB that was created for the service. If you go into the AWS console you should see an ELB that begins with that string. This will make your service externally accessible from outside your cluster.